# How to get specific reports by Id in C#

Tags: c#, database, model, report

The code generates all events of a specific producer, so that works. 
But the problem is that when I return new ApiListModel< EventPerYearReport >() it goes to the class ApiListModel and then it says "status_code": 200, "data": null.

How do I generate, by executing the following URL: /api/dashboard/1, a value instead of "status_code": 200, "data": null?

DashboardController.cs

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ApiListModel<EventPerYearReport>> GetEventPerYearReport(int id)
    {
        return await _dashboardService.GetEventPerYearReport(id);
    }
```

DashboardService.cs

```
    public async Task<ApiListModel<EventPerYearReport>> GetEventPerYearReport(int id)
    {
        var results = _dbContext.Events
            .Where(p => p.ProducerId == id)
            .GroupBy(e => e.DateStartEvent.ToString("yyyy"), (year, values) => new EventPerYear
            {
                year = year,
                total = values.Count(),
            }).ToList();

        var report = new EventPerYearReport()
        {
            eventsPerYear = results
        };
        return new ApiListModel<EventPerYearReport>();
    }
```

ApiListModel.cs

```
public class ApiListModel<T>
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status_code")]
    public int StatusCode = 200;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public List<T> Data;
}
```

EventPerYearReport.cs

```
public class EventPerYearReport
{
    public List<EventPerYear> eventsPerYear { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are asking here, are you asking why your code is returning "status_code": 200, "data": null everytime is it executed? 

If that is the case it is because you are returning `return new ApiListModel<EventPerYearReport>();` when you want to be returning `return new ApiListModel<EventPerYearReport>({ Data = new EventPerYearReport(){eventsPerYear = results}};`

Answer (score 0):

Your `DashboardService.cs` is returning `new ApiListModel<EventPerYearReport>();` this will always have null data.

To fix this you need to use the following

```
    public async Task<ApiListModel<EventPerYearReport>> GetEventPerYearReport(int id)
        {
            var results = _dbContext.Events
                .Where(p => p.ProducerId == id)
                .GroupBy(e => e.DateStartEvent.ToString("yyyy"), (year, values) 
    => new EventPerYear
                {
                    year = year,
                    total = values.Count(),
                }).ToList();
        return new ApiListModel<EventPerYearReport>()
        {
            Data = new EventPerYearRaport()
            {
                eventsPerYear = results
            }
        };
    }
```